# Font bitmap creator

Tags: fonts

I would like to create my font that use image icon instead of font alphabet. My image icon using 16 bit-color system. And generate the font table using "ttf" extension.
For example,

In the font table, I will insert my image icon place of "A" alphabet. So, when I type "A" alphabet, the screen of my application will represent the image icon.

I do not know what is the program that suitable for create font as my requirement.
Please, suggest me the suitable program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I try this one but I can't insert my image icon instead of some alphabet in font table. I don't know how to insert my image icon.

Comment: Sorry about that. Well, this app is for making bitmap fonts out of system installed fonts (TTF, etc.). Possibly you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

I made this one a while back. It can build compact power-of-two-sized font bitmaps, includes kerning, and includes source code to load and display the fonts

https://github.com/SudoMike/SudoFont